# SQL Outer Join?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have tables like these:

```
Fields (ID int, Name varchar(20))

ID     Name
===============
1      FieldName
2      FeildDesc

Container (ID int, Name varchar(100))

ID     Name
====================================
1      C1       
2      C2
3      C3

ContainerField (ContainerId int, FieldId int, FieldValue varchar(100))

ContainerId    FieldId    FieldValue
====================================
1              1          Container1
1              2          Container1 Desc
2              1          Container2
2              2          Container3 Desc
3              1          Container3
```

I'd like to have my result look like:

```
ContainerId    Name          Desc
===================================
1              Container1    Container1 Desc
2              Container2    Container2 Desc
3              Container3    NULL
```

I've tried to do LEFT OUTER JOIN between ContainerField and Field but that didn't seemt to work. I'd appreciate it if anyone could help.

Comment: "*that didn't seemt to work*" is not an acceptable error description

Comment: How didn't it work? What was the query you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the table twice, once for the names and once for the descriptions.

```
select
  c.Id as ContainerId,
  cfn.FieldValue as Name,
  cfd.FieldValue as Desc
from
  Container c
  left join ContainerField cfn
    on cfn.ContainerId = c.ID and cfn.FieldId = 1
  left join ContainerField cfd
    on cfd.ContainerId = c.ID and cfd.FieldId = 2
```

As you can see, not groups, or aggregations. Also, you don't really need the Fields tabel itself in the query, although it's good to have it in your database, because it enforces referential integrity (if you have the proper keys) and it provides a kind of documentation. But you might use an enum for that as well.

Alternatively, if you have not just two fields, but an unknown number of them, you might want to consider `pivot tables`. I must admit I'm not really good with those, especially in TSQL, so I'll provide you with just a link for you to explore: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx Or hopefully someone else can give you a specific example.

Answer (score 1):

No need for an outer join, an inner join will do it. You're also not using anything from `Container` (if you want to display the container name instead of ID, you can do an inner join with it to get that).

```
SELECT c.id AS ContainerID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN f.name = 'FieldName' THEN c.FieldValue END) AS Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN f.name = 'FieldDesc' THEN c.FieldValue END) AS `Desc`
FROM ContainerField AS c
JOIN Fields AS f ON c.FieldID = f.id
GROUP BY ContainerID
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdcf03/1)

Note that you have a misspelling in your `Fields` table: `FeildsDesc` should be `FieldsDesc`.

Comment: This will work. I don't think 'abusing' group by like this is the cleanest way, but then again, I've used this both in SO answers and in production code, so let's not be a hypocrite. +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Might as well throw in my two cents. This will get you what you need.  It's done in Oracle but should work the same.

EDIT: [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3902fa/3) for a working example.

```
Select * From (

WITH 
/* Example Tables.*/
Container As
(
    Select 1 as ID, 'C1' as Name From Dual Union All       
    Select 2 as ID, 'C2' as Name From Dual Union All
    Select 3 as ID, 'C3' as Name From Dual
)

,ContainerField as
(
    Select 1 as ContainerId, 1 as FieldId, 'Container1     ' as FieldValue From Dual UNION ALL
    Select 1 as ContainerId, 2 as FieldId, 'Container1 Desc' as FieldValue From Dual UNION ALL
    Select 2 as ContainerId, 1 as FieldId, 'Container2     ' as FieldValue From Dual UNION ALL
    Select 2 as ContainerId, 2 as FieldId, 'Container2 Desc' as FieldValue From Dual UNION ALL
    Select 3 as ContainerId, 1 as FieldId, 'Container3     ' as FieldValue From Dual
)

/*Code*/
Select
    C.ID, 
    Max(Case When CF.FieldId = 1 Then FieldValue End) as Name,
    Max(Case When CF.FieldId = 2 Then FieldValue End) as Descrption
From
    Container C
    Left Join ContainerField CF on C.ID = CF.ContainerID

Group By
    C.ID, 
    C.Name
Order By 
    C.ID
)
```

Output:

```
CONTAINERID     NAME        DESCRPTION
1               Container1  Container1 Desc
2               Container2  Container2 Desc
3               Container3
```

Comment: You may find http://sqlfiddle.com/ interesting.  You can then link to the query.  I only say that because I have MANY answers like yours on here.  I assure you that this is easier and looks more "professional"

Comment: By using `CF.ContainerID` you are cheating a bit, and it will fail if there is no matching ContainerField for a container for the fieldtype `Name`. You should `select`, `group by` and `order by` `C.ID` instead. Or, if you assume there is always a name field, then change the first join to `inner join` to make that assumption clear (and make the query more optimized). And once you fixed that, your answer is essentially the same as @Barmar's. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol Good catch!  I normally group in that method, but I think in a flurry I put the `ContainerID`, which is certainly unreliable.

Comment: @DanAndrews Thanks for the tip!  How's it now?  I will say I like the cheating `WITH` clause method, simply because I don't have access to inserts.  Query only for me :/

Comment: @Phillip You still forgot the one in `select`. Also, you `left join` the table `Fields`, but don't use it anywhere, so you can remove that join altogether.

Answer (score 0):

YOu do just seem to need a `left join`:

```
select c.id, c.name, cf.FieldValue
from Container c join
     ContainerField cf
     on cf.ContainerId = c.id and cf.FieldId = 2;
```

Of course, the data in your question is a bit misleading.  I'm assuming the `name` column is intended to come from the `Container` table.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after:

```
SELECT t1.ContainerId, t1.FieldValue, t2.FieldValue
FROM ContainerField t1
LEFT JOIN ContainerField t2 ON t1.ContainerId = t2.ContainerId 
      AND t1.FieldId = 1 and t2.FieldId = 2
```

EDIT ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5fdea/19/0)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ContainerId,
(
   SELECT t2.FieldValue FROM ContainerField t2
   WHERE t2.FieldId = 1 AND t1.ContainerId = t2.ContainerId

) AS [Name],
(
   SELECT t3.FieldValue FROM ContainerField t3
   WHERE t3.FieldId = 2 AND t1.ContainerId = t3.ContainerId
) AS [Desc]
FROM ContainerField t1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this doesn't show the last row which has a NULL as the Desc column.

Comment: I think this might work if you move the condition `t1.FieldId = 1` to the where clause. If you don't, then I think there is no condition that prevents t1 from also returning the 'type 2' fields.

Comment: **@notlkk**, I update my answer to show that you can get your desired results via just the on table (`ContainerField`).  See my edit.

Comment: I think you meant `ContainerField t1` to be `Container t1` in the second query (and `t1.ContainerId` should become `t1.ID` then, in both subselects).